# Is $Cat$, the category of all the small categories, a small category?

Tags: category-theory

Does $Cat$, the category of all the small categories, contain $Cat$ itself? I.e. is $Cat$ a small category?

The following quote from Categories from the Working Mathematicians says $\times  : Cat \times Cat \to Cat$ is a functor. Does it mean that the domain $Cat \times Cat$ is a (small) category, and $Cat$ is a (small) category?

> The product  $\times$  is  thus a  pair of functions:  To each pair $(B, C)$ of categories,  a  new  category  $B \times  C$;  to  each  pair  of functors  $(U, V)$,  a  new functor  $U  \times  V$.  Moreover,  when  the  composites  $U'  U$  and  $V'   V$  are  defined,  one  clearly  has  $(U'  \times  V')  (U \times V) =  U'  U  \times  V'V$.  Hence  the 
>   operation  $\times$  itself is a functor;  more exactly, on restricting to small categories, it is a functor $\times  : Cat \times Cat \to Cat$.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, *elements of* $Cat$ are small categories - $Cat\times Cat$ is the domain, and $Cat$ the codomain, of $\times$. Analogously, "a function on natural numbers" would be $f:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow\mathbb{N}$ but that wouldn't imply that $\mathbb{N}$ is a natural number.

Indeed, $Cat$ itself is not a small category, since there are a proper class of small categories *(easy exercise: there is a category of cardinality $\kappa$ for every cardinal $\kappa$)*.

(Of course, $Cat$ is **locally** small - given any two small categories there are only set-many functors between them - but it's not small.)

Comment: Thanks. According to the definition of a functor, its domain and codomain both are categories. $×:Cat×Cat→Cat$ is a functor. So are the domain $Cat×Cat$ and codomain $Cat$  (small) categories?

Comment: @Tim The domain and codomain are **non-small** categories.